# DropdownButtonFormField with validation is untappable if field is invalid

Tags: flutter

I'm having the following code statement.

```
Container(
    height: 50,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
    child: DropdownButtonFormField(
          isExpanded: true,
          validator: (value) => value == 0 ? errorMessage : null,
          items: items
              .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text(e,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                      style: Style.poppinsRegularTextStyleWith(
                          fontSize: 14, color: color12)),
                  value: items.indexOf(e)))
              .toList(),
          value: selectedIndex,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedIndex = value;
              if (onChanged != null) {
                onChanged(items[value]);
              }
            });
          },
        ),
      )
```

After submitting the form the dropdown that has error message becomes unresponsive to tap, what i'm doing wrong?

How should i change the validator or what other fix is there for this

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace the code with it

```
                    DropdownButtonFormField(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    validator: (value) => value == 0 ? errorMessage : null,
                    items: items.map((e) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: e,
                        child: Text(e),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                          if (onChanged != null) {
                            onChanged(items[value]);
                          }
                        })),
```

I am using DropdownButtonFormField in my code and it works perfect it is like;

```
                DropdownButtonFormField(
                  value: _currentSugars ?? userData.sugars,
                  items: sugars.map((sugar) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: sugar,
                      child: Text('$sugar sugars'),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentSugars = val),
                ),
```

Comment: The validator function is missing from this example

Comment: if you mean my second code, you can add validator instead of value: _currentSugars ?? userData.sugars,. Did you replace the first code with yours. is it work ?

Comment: I replaced it and i saw that the problem was the extra height in the container

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the extra height on the container, making the dropdown and error message, this was causing some overlap and the tappable area wasn't there anymore.

````
    **height: 50, <= Issue was here**
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
    child: DropdownButtonFormField(
          isExpanded: true,
          validator: (value) => value == 0 ? errorMessage : null,
          items: items
              .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text(e,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                      style: Style.poppinsRegularTextStyleWith(
                          fontSize: 14, color: color12)),
                  value: items.indexOf(e)))
              .toList(),
          value: selectedIndex,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedIndex = value;
              if (onChanged != null) {
                onChanged(items[value]);
              }
            });
          },
        ),
      )```
````